# Omit property of base class for all implementations in Autofixture

Tags: autofixture

I have classes for example as follows:

```
public class BaseItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Language Language { get; set; }
}

public class ItemA : BaseItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ItemB : BaseItem
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

I want to omit the property `Language` everytime I create `ItemA`, `ItemB` or any future implementations of `BaseItem` class.

I added this line (below) in my customization class but in the generation of `ItemA`/ `ItemB`, *AutoFixture* still attempts to generate the `Language` property.

```
fixture.Register<BaseItem>(() => { return fixture.Build<BaseItem>().Without(i => i.Language).Create(); });
```

Omitting the property on implementation class level like this (see below) works.

```
fixture.Register<ItemA>(() => { return fixture.Build<ItemA>().Without(i => i.Language).Create(); });
```

My questions are:

1. How can I implement a generic way to do this so I don't have to customize each implementation class?
2. If there's a way to do #1, how can I override it in case I want the Language property to be generated for some exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Q1

In order to target (or, rather, *omit*) a property defined on a base class, I know of no better way than defining a custom `ISpecimenBuilder`, in this case something like:

```
public class OmitLanguageBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var pi = request as PropertyInfo;
        if (pi != null &&
            pi.PropertyType == typeof(Language)
            && pi.Name == "Language"
            && pi.DeclaringType == typeof(BaseItem))
            return new OmitSpecimen();

        return new NoSpecimen();
    }
}
```

This specifically handles requests for the `Language` property only declared on `BaseItem`. If you want to be less specific, you can remove some of the predicates in the `if` expression. When AutoFixture gets such a request, it'll interpret the special 'signal type' `OmitSpecimen` as an instruction to ignore that property.

You can register `OmitLanguageBuilder` with a `Fixture` instance directly (although you should package it in a *Customization*. This test passes:

```
[Fact]
public void Q1A()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customizations.Add(new OmitLanguageBuilder());

    var actual = fixture.Create<ItemA>();

    Assert.Null(actual.Language);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(Guid), actual.Id);
    Assert.NotNull(actual.Name);
}
```

A similar test for `ItemB` passes as well.

## Q2

When you want to populate `Language` in special test cases, the easiest solution may simply be to populate it after the fact:

```
[Fact]
public void Q2SetAfter()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customizations.Add(new OmitLanguageBuilder());

    var actual = fixture.Create<ItemA>();
    actual.Language = fixture.Create<Language>();

    Assert.NotNull(actual.Language);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(Guid), actual.Id);
    Assert.NotNull(actual.Name);
}
```

Another option is to use the `Build` API:

```
[Fact]
public void Q2Build()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customizations.Add(new OmitLanguageBuilder());

    var actual = 
        fixture.Build<ItemA>().With(x => x.Language, fixture.Create<Language>()).Create();

    Assert.NotNull(actual.Language);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(Guid), actual.Id);
    Assert.NotNull(actual.Name);
}
```

And finally, if you need to change how AutoFixture handles the type in general, you can do something like this:

```
[Fact]
public void Q2Customize()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customizations.Add(new OmitLanguageBuilder());
    fixture.Customize<ItemA>(c => c.With(x => x.Language, fixture.Create<Language>()));

    var actual = fixture.Create<ItemA>();

    Assert.NotNull(actual.Language);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(Guid), actual.Id);
    Assert.NotNull(actual.Name);
}
```

Comment: Q1 works like a charm :) I've implemented it in a generic way as the PropertyTypeOmitter.

Regarding Q2, I'm wondering is there a way to access fixture in the test method when the fixture is created using customization attribute?

So [Theory][CustomAutoData] for example

Comment: @AdeliaBernalius You can add an `IFixture` argument to your test methods.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know i could do that :D thanks Mark!